# Is there a special name (and if so what is it) for this flush-style SMA variant?

Tags: jargon, connectors

I have some radios that have a special antenna connector. It looks like an SMA connector, but the dielectric is flush with the end of the connector:

[image: SMA-like connector where dielectric is flush with end of connector]

rather than recessed the way "normal" SMA connectors are:

[image: Normal SMA connector with recessed dielectric]

The consequence of this is that the recessed connector and the flush connector are incompatible.

Does anyone know what to call the flush-style connector?

Comment: Motorola uses the flush style.  Adapting them is possible but more annoying than it needs to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is known as an SF style SMA connector. It is also commonly known as a Motorola SMA connector since they seem to be one of the few large scale users of this style connector

You can find some adapters for this style of connector such as this RFB-1142-4 BNC adapter:

[image]

[`http://www.hitechwireless.com/rf-industries-rfb-1142-4-bnc-f-sma-f-adapter/`](http://www.hitechwireless.com/rf-industries-rfb-1142-4-bnc-f-sma-f-adapter/)

Comment: These work for Motorola radios too.  They are still recessed, but they reach much deeper into the socket.  I'm going to grind off the excess a bit.

Comment: Apparently my link was removed above.  Just search Amazon for "DHT Electronics 2pcs RF coaxial coax adapter SMA female to BNC female".